# JOIN a table to the MAX records from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, join, aggregate-functions

Let's say that I have a MySQL database for an online Forum with two tables :

```
topic : id, ...
message : id, id_topic, created, ...
```

One **topic** could have many (or no) **messages**, as you'd expect.

I would like to get a list of every **topic** record LEFT JOIN'ed to its *most recently-created* **message** record (or joined to nothing, if there are no messages). I need all fields of both records in the result.

What I've been doing is using a sub-query to make a table of all the most recently-created messages, then joining it to the topic table. However it really bogs down when the topic table has a few thousand rows and the message table has a few hundred thousand.

What is the correct way to solve this problem, with an eye toward performance?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT t.*, m.*
 FROM topic t
 LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT id_topic, MAX(created) AS created
    FROM message
    GROUP BY id_topic
   ) T2 ON t.id = T2.id_topic
 LEFT JOIN message m ON m.id_topic = T2.id_topic AND m.created = T2.created
```

**Explanation:**

First, we are joining the table topic with a temp table having maximum created for each id_topic. Then the table message is joined with the same temp table. And then the result are fetched from both tables.

Comment: Thanks, Raging Bull. I take this as confirmation that the sub-query is necessary. Perhaps the slowness I'm seeing is coming from somewhere else (MySQL 5.5). I feel the join on id_topic+created is a little "clumsy" but I don't know of a different approach either. 2 messages with the same id_topic+created timestamp (which happens surprisingly often) will both get picked up by the second join, creating duplicate rows in the result.In the future I might investigate adding and maintaining the column "id_message_newest" to my topic table, and simplify my SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. It should have good performance too
(provided your `message` table is properly indexed).

```
SELECT t.*, m3.*
FROM
topic t
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT m1.id_topic, max(m1.id) id
   FROM
   message m1
   GROUP BY m1.id_topic
) m2 ON t.id = m2.id_topic
LEFT JOIN message m3 ON m2.id = m3.id
```

Comment: Interesting point about the indexes; perhaps that's where performance is taking a hit. I have indexes set up on id (unique, both tables), id_topic, created, and id_topic+created (for the sub-query), but maybe I've missed something. I just kind of create these by-ear…

Comment: Try adding an index covering both id_topic (first) and then id on the table message